# "how the moon __ constructed", was or is?

Tags: passive-voice

A question in a test puzzled me.

> Because it means we have the chance to obtain information about how the moon __ constructed.

The answer to this question is "is".

Can "was" be applied to this context?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The moon was not constructed.

Comment: The word *____ constructed* should be replaced by *was formed*. It's a badly constructed sentence.

Answer (score -1):

construct= to build something or put together different parts to form something whole

It is better to use...how the moon  constructed.

(We normally say 'The wall  constructed of concrete.' 'The chair is made of wood.')

We can also say... how the moon   constructed.- present perfect tense

...how the moon  constructed.- simple past tense

Comment: the meaning of constructed would change based on "is" or "was". Using "Is" means we are referring the composition of the Moon (geographical, chemical, etc), "Was" means the sequence of events which brought the Moon into being...

Comment: It would not make sense to say “how the moon has been constructed” unless it’s referring to some “artificial” moon, like a prop or model.